# AWS Elastic Beanstalk not running npm in production mode

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, npm-install, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When deploying to Elastic Beanstalk, the devDependencies in my package.json are attempting to be installed and failing.

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-activity.log
-------------------------------------
      node_version_manager.run_npm_install(options.app_path)
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 136, in run_npm_install
      self.npm_install(bin_path, self.config_manager.get_container_config('app_staging_dir'))
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 180, in npm_install
      raise e
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v10.16.0-linux-x64/bin/npm', '--production', 'rebuild']' returned non-zero exit status 1 (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: + /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py --action npm-install
  npm WARN @angular/common@8.2.3 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
  npm WARN @angular/core@8.2.3 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
  npm WARN @angular/core@8.2.3 requires a peer of zone.js@~0.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
  npm WARN @angular/forms@8.2.3 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
  npm WARN @angular/router@8.2.3 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
  npm WARN ng-recaptcha@4.3.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

  audited 16371 packages in 8.64s
  found 1 low severity vulnerability
    run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

  > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/core-js
  > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

  [96mThank you for using core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock/core-js [96m) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library![0m

  [96mThe project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: [0m
  [96m>[94m https://opencollective.com/core-js [0m
  [96m>[94m https://www.patreon.com/zloirock [0m

  [96mAlso, the author of core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock [96m) is looking for a good job -)[0m


  > spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/spawn-sync
  > node postinstall


  > core-js@3.1.4 postinstall /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/core-js
  > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

  [96mThank you for using core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock/core-js [96m) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library![0m

  [96mThe project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: [0m
  [96m>[94m https://opencollective.com/core-js [0m
  [96m>[94m https://www.patreon.com/zloirock [0m

  [96mAlso, the author of core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock [96m) is looking for a good job -)[0m


  > pre-commit@1.2.2 install /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/pre-commit
  > node install.js


  > cypress@3.4.1 postinstall /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/cypress
  > node index.js --exec install

  Installing Cypress (version: 3.4.1)

  [?25l[14:03:36]  Downloading Cypress     [started]
  [?25hinternal/streams/legacy.js:57
        throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
        ^

  Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/cypress/cypress.zip'
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno 1
  npm ERR! cypress@3.4.1 postinstall: `node index.js --exec install`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR! 
  npm ERR! Failed at the cypress@3.4.1 postinstall script.
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
  npm ERR!     /tmp/.npm/_logs/2019-08-25T14_03_36_147Z-debug.log
  Running npm install:  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v10.16.0-linux-x64/bin/npm
  Setting npm config jobs to 1
  npm config jobs set to 1
  Running npm with --production flag
  Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details.
  UTC 2019/08/25 14:03:36 cannot find application npm debug log at /tmp/deployment/application/npm-debug.log 

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 695, in <module>
      main()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 677, in main
      node_version_manager.run_npm_install(options.app_path)
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 136, in run_npm_install
      self.npm_install(bin_path, self.config_manager.get_container_config('app_staging_dir'))
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 180, in npm_install
      raise e
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v10.16.0-linux-x64/bin/npm', '--production', 'rebuild']' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

The devDependencies should not install at all, but notice how the output includes this line:

> Running npm without --production flag

I don't understand why. According to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-packagejson.html), it should run in production mode by default. I also tried configuring the environment manually using 3 different techniques in `.ebextensions`.

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    NODE_ENV: production
    NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION: true
    NPM_USE_PRODUCTION: false
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:
    NodeCommand: "node dist/server"
```

This made `'--production'` start to appear on line 6 in the log above, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Why is it trying to install the devDependencies and how can I stop it?

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @Parth, unfortunately no. If I remember correctly, this was about the time I was planning to switch my instance to use Docker anyway, so I did that and this became a non-issue.